# Encontrar la posición en una matriz (lista de listas)

Tags: python, lista, matrices, método, indices

Tengo una lista de listas en la que necesito encontrar la posición estilo [x, y] en la que se encuentra un elemento ( en este caso son puros strings ), y tengo diseñada una función respecto a mi código, que en este caso es un código orientado a objetos, que es la siguiente:

```
def posicion(jugada, tablero):
    for c in range(len(tablero)):
        for x in range(len(tablero[c])):
            if jugada == ((tablero[c][x]).numero+(tablero[c][x]).color):
                return [c, x]
```

dado que tablero es un objeto que creo en mi código, tiene esos parámetros de .numero y .color que van ligados directamente al self del objeto. Mi pregunta es si existe algún método o algo, parecido al .index() que se usa en las listas, que yo ponga un elemento y busque en esta lista de listas o matriz, y que me devuelva los indices.

Comment: Tendrías un par de opciones creo. Por ejemplo, si es una lista de listas, sería muy sencillo hacer un `np.array(LISTA)` y con la función `where` de numpy, podrías obtenerlo. Te deojo [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18079151/12580704) un link a una pregunta similar ya resuelta.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!